# Stop adding strength points to database

Tags: php, mysql

Following query adds 1 strength to the chosen player:

```
 UPDATE uzytkownicy SET strenght = strenght + 1 WHERE player = ?
```

Now I want the player to stop adding more strength if it is 99.

```
if($strenght >= 99)
{
    //YOU CAN NOT ADD MORE STRENGHT
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: Add a constraint so that strength < 100.

Comment: You can store the limits for each player/attribute in a separate table - or a WHERE clause. Or handle the logic externally

Comment: Add " AND strenght<100" to your UPDATE Statement. But you should clearify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the logic in the update:

```
UPDATE uzytkownicy
    SET strength = strength + 1
    WHERE player = ? and strength < 99;
```

This works for a fix limit for each player.  If you want a custom limit for each player, then you need to store that information somewhere and join it in.

Comment: His column is defined as "strenght" (not "strength").

Comment: Everyone sees the error, he is tactfully correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 'game settings' table where you store maximum values for player attributes. That way you don't have to update your game code to make changes on limits of player attribute values.

```
UPDATE uzytkownicy SET strength = strength + 1
WHERE player = ?
AND strength < (SELECT maxStrength FROM gameSettings);
```

But if you want to have the same structure as in your question you should just move your query execution inside the IF statement:

```
if($strength < 99){
    // run your update query here
    // UPDATE uzytkownicy SET strength = strength + 1 WHERE player = ?
}
```